# How to convert a char array to a number for sorting?

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's say I have three words I want to sort:

- hello
- goodbye
- alex

And alphabetically it'd be sorted ascendingly as `["alex", "goodbye", "hello"]`. Is there a way to convert the string (limited to 100 characters)? For example, if I have:

```
['a', 'l', 'e', 'x']
```

And I use `ord` to get the code for each list element:

```
[1, 12, 5, 24]
```

How would I create a number from that, that would also be smaller than, say, `goodbye`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```py
from operator import mul, pow
from itertools import repeat

LIMIT = 100
char_vals = [1, 12, 5, 24]
sum(map(mul, char_vals, map(pow, repeat(27), range(LIMIT - 1, -1, -1))))
```

---

Since you've bounded the length of the strings, you can think of each word as a base-27 number. 0 represents that the letter doesn't exist, 1 represents `a`, 2 represents `b`, etc.

Then, the numerical value of each word can be computed using the following polynomial:

```
i_1 * 27**99 + i_2 * 27**98 + ...
```

where `char_vals = [i_1, i_2, ... i_{len(original_string)}]` (i.e. each `i` is the integer value of the corresponding letter, and `i`s that are past the end of the array correspond to zeroes).

Comment: thanks for this! If, for example, we were using a different alphabet, say Russian or Mandarin, how would the above change?

Comment: Change the base for each term of the polynomial to the number of letters in the alphabet (plus one). This might be fine for Russian, but I'm not so sure about Chinese.

Comment: I see, ok, so if the "alphabet" was base-64, we'd set the exponent to 65?

Comment: Yes. You have to add one to account for the fact that words aren't necessarily the same length.

Comment: why start the power at 100 and not at 0 to be more in line with the regular positional notation scheme?

Comment: I mean, star the power from 0 and start going up `i_1 * 27**0 + i_2 * 27**1 + ...`

Comment: No, you can't do that since the strings you're comparing may not be of the same length.

Comment: and what is the difference?

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said. The issue is that you could have something like "abaaaaaa" versus "b" -- the first string should come before the second, but your proposed method would reverse this.

Answer (score 0):

If we limit the array to N characters, we could do something like this:

```
words = ["hello", "goodbye", "alex"]
LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET = 26

def num_from_string(s, max_length=10):
    num = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(s):
        num += ord(char) * ((LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET+1) ** (max_length-i))
    return num

sorted(words, key=num_from_string)
# ['alex', 'goodbye', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use map and a lambda function. Python "ord" doesn't work on lists, just characters.

```
    # Original list
    words = ["hello", "goodbye", "alex"]
    # Ordinals
    words = list(map(lambda word: ord(word[0]), words))
    # To sort it: 
    words = sorted(words)
```

Comment: that only takes the first letter into account though?